# Why pm2 monit has no logs?

Tags: logging, pm2

given this code

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('testings..');
}, 2000);
```

and running this..

```
npx pm2 start tester.js
```

then running this..

`pm2 monit`

Nothing is printed to log in monit.
Why?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
You have to specify a directory for the apps logs, like:

```
pm2 start someapp --time --log /somedirectory
```

After that, `pm2 monit` starts to show the logs.